# Django-Rest-Framework, how to remove metadata from results

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a ListApiView set up, for the JQuery UI Autocomplete. 
It is filtering correctly, but the results are wrapped with some metadata

```
{
    "count": 710, 
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/taxonomy/lookup/?term=hom&page=3", 
    "previous": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/taxonomy/lookup/?term=hom&page=1", 
    "results": [
        {
            "label": "Homaledra sabalella", 
            "value": "Homaledra sabalella"
        }, 
        {
            "label": "Homaledra sabalella (Chambers, 1880)", 
            "value": "Homaledra sabalella (Chambers, 1880)"
        },
        .....
        ... 
    }
}
```

Where about can I configure it so that I only return the "results" list?
Looking around the documentation it seems to be the renderer. How do I set this in a ListApiView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those "metadata" comes from the `PaginationSerializer`, 
the default `list` method wrap your `serializer_class` into a `PaginationSerializer`.

you can override `list` method:

```
class ViewSet(GenericViewSet): 
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        # If you want response all the results, without pagination, 
        # stop calling the self.paginate_queryset method, use queryset directly
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset) or queryset
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Upvoted as correct, but you might want to change the `instance` variable name to `queryset`. Being called `instance` implies that it's a variable pointing to a single model instance.

Comment: @TomChristie thx...I copied that code from old version of DRF, and I noticed DRF fixed and improved a lot of details just now. thanks again!